# how would you use subscription managers with meteor's template subscriptions?

Tags: templates, meteor, publish-subscribe

Meteor recently introduced template subscription capabilities. You can now call `this.subscribe` from within a `Temeplate.xyz.onCreated` call and the helper {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}} will only be true once the subscriptions have gotten ready from the server.

Unfortunately this does not seem to be obviously compatible with [subs-manager](https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager) or [subs-Cache](https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-subs-cache)

How woudl you use subs-Cache in-place of this.subscribe such that the subscription ids made by the subsciptions manager make it into _subscriptionHandles and _allSubsReady part of this.subscribe? Or otherwise asked, how do you get {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}} and the function Template.instance().subscriptionsReady() to depend on Template subscriptions made with subs-Cache.

Example code that does not work:

```
# in some top level file
share.subsCache = new SubsCache( 
  expireAter: 5  
  cacheLimit: 10
)

#in a template file
Template.entryRevisionInfo.onCreated ->
  share.subsCache.subscribe('somePub')
```

Comment: no sorry I haven't, I'll add a bounty though to see if that perks anything up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sacha Greif wrote a solution in the [Telescope](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope) app. I've tried to extract the parts that are significant to a basic implementation below. As far as I understand it relies on explicitly setting the ready status of the template... setting it reactively when the subscription is ready:

```
subsManager = new SubsManager();
Template.templatename.onCreated(function () {
   var instance = this;
   instance.ready = new ReactiveVar(false);
   subscription = subsManager.subscribe('yourCollection')
   instance.autorun(function () {
     if (subscription.ready()) {  //reactive
       instance.ready.set(true);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/  as well

Answer (score 3):

The [next (unreleased) version](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md) of meteor has a `connection` option to `TemplateInstance#subscribe`, and I would expect that you would be able to pass a subscription manager as the "connection."